# Simile timeline layout issue in IE8 and IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, jsp

National Science Foundation installed v.2.3.1 of the Simile Timeline on the nsf.gov website in 2009. The timeline can be viewed at http://www.nsf.gov/news/special_reports/history-nsf/timeline/index.jsp. At that time, there were no browser compatibility issues. We are now having 
layout issues with the timeline in IE8 and IE9, but not with Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

The IE 9 developer toolbar was deployed to check Javascript issues and no errors were reported. It was suggested at http://code.google.com/p/simile-widgets/issues/detail?id=428 that the layout issue can be rectified by changing “className” to “class” in timeline-bundle.js in the simile-widgets exhibits. This change was carried out, but did not fix the layout. Then a global change was carried 
out but this too did not fix the layout. Then, the nsfhistory.js file was examined but the layout problem persisted.

Would you have any suggestion what we could do to rectify the layout problem with the Simile timeline in IE8 and IE9? If it can be fixed, then we’ll be able to keep the timeline on the nsf.gov website.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Steve

Comment: if there are no JS errors, then it may just be CSS problems.  Using the developer tools, inspect what styles are actual being used by the element rendering incorrectly.

Comment: works fine for me in IE8, other than being selectable which detracts from user experience.